# Overfull multi-processing pipe() causing delays between socket client and dash client

Tags: python, python-3.x, multiprocessing, pipe, plotly-dash

I am communicating the last return from my server through the client to a dashboard. Both the client and the dashboard are running as a separate process, using `multiprocessing`. Currently, I am communicating the received package through a `pipe()`. When displaying the `plotly dash`-dashboard, I am using `@app.callback` with a 1 second interval.

This results in the pipe being cramped and my values being updated with a huge delay.

**Dashboard code**

```py
def dashboard():
    app = dash.Dash()
    app.layout = html.Div([
        dcc.Interval(
            id="interval-components",
            interval=1*1000,
            n_intervals=0
        ),

        # dcc.Graph(figure=fig)
        daq.Gauge(
            id='gauge-chart',
            color={"gradient": True, "ranges": {
                "green": [0, 10], "yellow": [10, 30], "red": [30, 60]}},
            value=0,
            max=60,
            min=0,
            units="M/S",
        )
    ], className='row', style={'textAlign': 'center'})
    @app.callback(
        output=[Output('gauge-chart', 'value')],
        inputs=[Input('interval-components', 'n_intervals')]
    )
    def update_gauge(n):
        value = receive_packet(child_conn)[0][2]
        return [value]

    app.run_server(port=8047,debug=True)

def receive_packet(conn):
    packet = conn.recv()
    packet = list(map(int, packet))
    return [packet]
```

**Multiprocessing**

```py
    parent_conn, child_conn = multiprocessing.Pipe()
    p1 = multiprocessing.Process(target=get_data, args=(parent_conn, address,))
    p2 = multiprocessing.Process(target=dashboard, args=())
    p3 = multiprocessing.Process(target=receive_packet, args=(child_conn, ))

    p1.start()
    p2.start()
    p3.start()

    p1.join()
    p2.join()
    p3.join()
```

**get_data sending into the pipe**

```py
#SOME CODE TO RECEIVE THE PACKAGES FROM THE SERVER
while True:
   conn.send([can_id, an1, anVar, connected, time_since_valid])
```

Is there a better way to share data between processes, without blocking the stream? Maybe shared states?

**FAILED FIX 1**

I already tried to fix it, by letting the `get_data` process `time.sleep(1)`, to match the interval. This doesn't seem to work.

**FAILED FIX 2**

I tried to add some *I am ready* messages, but this does not solve the problem:

```py
def receive_packet(conn = child_conn):
    conn.send("GIMMI DATA")
    packet = conn.recv()
    conn.send("0")
    packet = list(map(int, packet))
    return [packet]


def get_data(conn = parent_conn):
    #################
    ####SOME CODE####
    #################
    packet = conn.recv()
    if packet == "GIMMI DATA":
        conn.send([can_id, an1, anVar, connected, time_since_valid])
    else:
        pass
```

Answer (score 0):

**SUCCESFUL FIX 1**

Instead of running `multiprocessing.Pipe()` I fell back to using `multiprocessing.Value()`, which seems to be way more stable for constant datastreams.
Suggestions for more efficient solutions are always welcome.